# Downloading data and processing asynchronous with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to download xml files and then I want to do different processing to this files, like parsing them:

```
-(void)parseFeed:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [FeedSessionManager.sharedManager.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error)
                                  {
                                      Parser* parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithData:data];

                                      [self.feeds addObjectsFromArray:[parser items]];

                                  }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Parser object will parse the xml file using `NSXMLParser`. The `parseFeed:(NSURL*)url` is called from the `ViewController`:

```
Downloader* downloader = [[Downloader alloc] init];
[downloader parseFeed:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.engadget.com/tag/features/rss.xml"]];
NSArray* items = [downloader feeds];
```

And this is how I create the `NSURLSession` object:

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:FeedSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Of course this approach doesn't work for me. Inside `parseFeed` method I want to wait until all data is downloaded and processed. Only then I want to access the `self.feeds` array in the `ViewController`.

Can someone point me into the right direction into doing this ? Or maybe point me to a different approach ?

Comment: Why don't you use operation queue for downloading and after getting the downloading complete response from delegate you can start parse them and best thing you have control over downloading like priority and pause and cancel

Comment: @Retro: thanks for the suggestion, can you also provide an example of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used ASIHTTPRequest but now no longer maintained but you can use AFHTTPClient's operation queue

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil];

// Important if only downloading one file at a time
[client.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: 1];

NSArray *videoURLs; // An array of strings you want to download

for (NSString * videoURL in videoURLs) {

    // …setup your requests as before

    [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:downloadRequest];
}
```